# Windows 8.1: Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed

Tags: vagrant

This question is one that I will answer in the hope that anyone with the same problem will be able to fix the problem without too much head banging like I did!

I'd just installed VirtualBox (4.3.16) and Vagrant (1.3.5) as per the instructions on their site. All seemed pretty clear and easy until I got to the point of running the command: vagrant up

This immediately returned the error:

```
Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.

Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.
```

This is an amazing error message... Where am I supposed to find this PATH variable???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a lot of suggestions on how to fix it but none of them helped until I finally found someone mention that VirtualBox had renamed a variable name, I was yet to find where so after some more digging, this is the solution that finally got things working:

Look for the following file (default install path on Windows 8.1):

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.3.5\plugins\providers\virtualbox\driver\base.rb
```

Open this file in your favourite text editor and do a search and replace all instances of VBOX_INSTALL_PATH to VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH

Hope this helps someone starting out with Vagrant and VirtualBox!

Comment: Have you tried opening the file by right clicking and selecting "open as administrator"?

Comment: Or you can change the logic and change in your system properties the VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH variable to VBOX_INSTALL_PATH. Worked for me on windows 10

Answer (score 12):

You need to run `vagrant` from an elevated prompt, i.e. `cmd` needs to be "Run as administrator".

Vagrant (or `VBoxManage.exe`, for that matter) does not need to be in your `PATH` environment variable. The Virtual Box installer automatically sets the `VBOX_INSTALL_PATH` or `VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH` environment variable which is what Vagrant uses to look it up, but Vagrant cannot run it unless it's elevated.

Comment: This actually is the way to go on windows 8!

Comment: no it does not for me in windows 7.  I have virtualbox installed. I ran the `cmd` as admin then fired `vagrant up`. Same goddamn issue. I am guessing I have some network setup issue with VirtualBox itself.

Answer (score 1):

For Vagrant 1.6.5 and Virtual Box 4.3.18, I believe just **restarting the computer after installing virtual box was the trick** (I also reinstalled Vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, however I had a version of Vagrant from around 6 months ago so I updated to the latest version and that worked without any other changes.

https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @crmpicco , maybe they've updated it since September. :)